# how to install Excelsior JET 10.5 in linux?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I am trying to install Excelsior JET 10.5(http://www.excelsiorjet.com/evaluate) for make my j2ee web application into exe. I downloaded that jet-1050-eval-en-linux-x86-reg.bin(32 bit) and tried below commands,

```
$ cd /opt
$ chmod a+x ~/raptor4/downloads/jet-1050-eval-en-linux-x86.bin
$ sudo ~/raptor4/downloads/jet-1050-eval-en-linux-x86.bin
```

finally i got the OP such as below image,

[image]

After that **Evaluation has been successfully installed on your computer** i dont have idea how to run it and next step.

someone help me to install this one and run it.

Comment: It's better to post file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) as text instead of images.

Comment: Note that <JET-home> refers to the Jet home directory that you installed in, not an actual directory name.  Once you resolve that I think your problems will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

According to the to the output of the installer and the [User's Guide](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/pdf/jet-1000-ug-linux.pdf) (section 2.2, page 22), you should:

```
cd <JET-HOME>
. setenv
jetsetup -show-profiles
```

with `<JET-HOME>` being a place holder for the Jet installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxi6:i386 libxtst6:i386
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you please explain in a little more detail what this command does and how it solves the issue?